# Please remove the giant quotation mark from the CSS for blockquotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, style, css

The blockquote HTML tag is often used for things that are not literally quotations—[for example, in duplicate question notices](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/662/possible-duplicate-message-is-difficult-to-notice)—so the giant quotation mark is quite often incorrect or misleading.

Since fixing duplicate question notices to not be (erroneously, imho) tagged as "blockquotes" is clearly a request that is [falling on deaf ears](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80891/possible-duplicate-message-is-difficult-to-notice-on-english-se), can we at least just get rid of the giant quotation mark? It was a nice idea, but it'd be better to have no decoration than have a wrong misleading decoration.

Comment: to be perfectly honest I have never liked that giant quotation mark

Comment: I think this is (or rather, was) a case of throwing out the baby with the bathwater: because there are parts of the interface that are incorrectly marked up as blockquotes, we've gotten rid of the quote-like formatting of blockquotes.

Comment: @martha the giant blockquote graphic was rather obnoxious all by itself, putting aside any other concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Completed per [Minor design tweak](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/minor-design-tweak).

Comment: This has nothing to do with Jeff, but why was this downvoted? I assume someone was just letting off steam but why take it out on an informative answer that provides a relevant link to the action taken in response to the question/request?

Comment: @mrhen I don't take meta downvotes personally; on meta, a downvote can mean almost anything someone wants it to.

Comment: Fair enough. I am still trying to figure this all out. :)