# Duplicate notice not showing up

Tags: bug

I voted to close the following question as a duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/349088/142322.

The question already had one close vote, but not *as a duplicate*. After I voted, a mod voted to close as well, presumably not *as a duplicate*.

The problem is that the notice doesn't show the purported duplicate, and the usual comment about the possible duplicate didn't show up.

I'm logging this as a bug since it throws away useful information for the OP, namely, the link to the purported duplicate.

---

I thought there might be some information on Meta.ELU and Meta.SE, but the closest Meta questions I found were the following, none of which helped:

On Meta.ELU:

- ["Possible duplicate" message is difficult to notice](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/662/possible-duplicate-message-is-difficult-to-notice)

On Meta.SE from a search with the string "close duplicate missing notice is:question":

- [Improve “Close as exact duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50067/improve-close-as-exact-duplicate?s=1|0.4206)
- [For a gold badge user, how to "propose" for closing a question as duplicate without completely closing it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279984/for-a-gold-badge-user-how-to-propose-for-closing-a-question-as-duplicate-with?s=2|0.2978)
- [Why not remove the "close" link for questions with an active bounty?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134762/why-not-remove-the-close-link-for-questions-with-an-active-bounty?s=3|0.2061)
- [Should moderators close questions for reasons other than obvious violation of the rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78748/should-moderators-close-questions-for-reasons-other-than-obvious-violation-of-th?s=4|0.1283)
- [Editing - possible race condition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118323/editing-possible-race-condition?s=5|0.0854)
- [What's with all the PHP hate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146837/whats-with-all-the-php-hate?s=6|0.0553)

Comment: The comment won't show up if the question has already been linked to.

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks for that information - I wasn't aware of it. Nevertheless, I still think it's a bug. I linked to two questions but voted to close the question as a duplicate of only one of them. There's also no guarantee in general that citing a link in comments cites that link as *the* duplicate, or even as a duplicate at all.